# Stopping Python Cell and still getting the data

Tags: python, infinite-loop, interrupt, freeze

I did a huge mistake in my while loop, which is scrapping data from some websites. I just figured it out after running it already for 2h. Is there a way that I can freeze/ stop the running cell and still get the df that was created? Maybe can I edit the running cell? I dont think so, at least I wasnt able to find anything online.

```
data = []
while != Condition
    info = driver.find_element(by.xpath, "//path")
    data.append([info])
    button_click = driver.find().click()

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[Info])
df.to_excel("name.xlsx", index=false)
```

This is like a short version of the code I'm running. Is it possible to get the df even though I will be forced to interrupt the cell in a while?

Thanks

Did not stop it yet, because the data isn't fully collected so far.

Comment: You can stop the loop and the `data` list will contain all the `[info]` accumulated so far. You will have to build the dataset in the next cell since the lines after the loop won't be executed if you interrupt the loop.

Comment: @alec_djinn do I need to take care of anything or just press control+c?

Comment: You should have a "stop" button in your notebook top bar. Hit that one.

Comment: @alec_djinn btw it did work. I interrupted the cell and the data was all saved in the variable. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score -1):

If you use spyder for executing the code you can stop the execution and still get the results computed so far.

Comment: No, Im using vs code

Comment: With vs code is not possible, you have to change to spyder

Comment: If you run in interactive mode `python -i myprogram.py` it's possible with any IDE.

Comment: but when you stop the script you will loose the variables